Sequence of shapes with lines and dot
This is another puzzle from Lanrt-F IQ test that was posted on Reddit
https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2Fmy-favourite-2-problems-from-lanrt-f-v0-58puclks5a6d1.png%3Fwidth%3D740%26format%3Dpng%26auto%3Dwebp%26s%3Daf3b35d7205c007bff0a8fbc8e59addc2813f24a


Answers

 1 and 2.

Explanation:

 The circle is pointless. Look at the types of interactions between the lines in each box. Lines will either intersect with each other and continue their path toward the edge of the box, or collide and end at the intersecting point.

 Next, complete any unfinished vectors, and count the number of triangles in each box. You should get 8, 5, 2, ?, ?, 1, which follows the sequence a0=8; an=|an-1-3| or 8, 5, 2, "1, 2", 1, ...

 Giving respect to the two types of interactions, there's only one answer with one triangle and that answer is 1, and one answer with 2 triangles and that is answer 2, giving answers 1 and 2.


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

@Will.Octagon.Gibson Thank you!
